# Salesforce app + Git + TeamCity = how to set up "save to server" step?

Tags: ant, salesforce, teamcity, integration, continuous

I am setting up continuous integration for SalesForce application.

I am new in SalesForce, and don't know how to automate some steps in my workflow. Please help me understand.

**My build steps in TeamCity:**

1. Get the branch with application code from git repository.
2. Save the updated code to my development org - this should automate the
   "Save to Server" command that the developer clicks in Eclipse.
3. Run unit tests using Ant tool.
4. Get the branch with Selenium tests code from git repository.
5. Run the selenium tests.
6. If the tests are green, merge the develop branch to QA branch and deploy the code changes from development org to QA org for manual testing.

**Problem: I don't know how to set up Step 2**

As far as I understand everything should be automated. I have been told by my manager that it's the developer's job to manually click 'save to server' command in Eclipse and then push the code changes to git repository. Also SalesForce does the so called build on its own in the cloud.

I would appreciate any explanations, references and examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce Migration Tool which relies on Apache's Ant for this as well. My approach was designing a Perl program that lists all modified, or added files within a branch and then saves them to the server using Ant.

For more information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm
(Deployment in this case is saving to the server)

EDIT: spelling mistake